# How do I fix the error of 'Could not cast value of type'?

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I am having an issue with this error. If keeps going to my segue. Is there a way to fix this. Any and all help is much appreciated.

Here's my View Controller

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    ***let rvc = segue.destinationViewController as! WebViewController***
    rvc.currentCollege = currentCollege
}
```

And heres my class:

```
import Foundation

class College {
    var webView = String()
    var name = String()
    var description = String()
    var location = String()
    var numberOfStudents = String()
    var image = String()


    init(Name n: String,Description d: String,Location l: String,NumberOfStudents s: String,Image i:String, WebView w: String) {
        name = n
        description = d
        location = l
        numberOfStudents = s
        image = i
        webView = w
    }
    init(){
        name = ""
        description = ""
        image = ""
        webView = ""
    }
}

 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { 
        let currentCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell")!
        let currentCollege = collegeArray[indexPath.row]
        currentCell.textLabel!.text = currentCollege.name
        currentCell.detailTextLabel?.text = currentCollege.location
        return currentCell
    }
```

Comment: what is your currentCollege in WebViewController type and what is the type of currentCollege

Comment: This is what i have in web view controller                                                       var currentCollege = College()

Comment: And what is currentCollege coming from what is its value. Can you add some more code.

Comment: still its not clear....need more code where you are declaring currentCollege. I dont need to see actual class defination. Paste your code for WebViewController and and your viewController

Comment: If you're using an initializer in your class you don't need to instantiate your properties like this: *var webView = String()*, just do this *var webView : String*

Comment: Thanks but thats not the issue. Never had that issue

Comment: I'm not telling you it's the issue, I'm telling you how to write better code

Comment: On which line does the error occur?

Comment: Have you set the class of the custom view controller to `WebViewController` in Interface Builder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing that destinationViewController is not a WebViewController. Perhaps WebViewController is embedded in a navigation controller You could do something like:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if let rvc = segue.destinationViewController as? WebViewController {
        rvc.currentCollege = currentCollege
    }
}
```

To avoid force down casting in prepareForSegue.